# After Newsletter Subscription,Confirmation Message Should be display on top instead of bottom on Home Page

Tags: magento2.2.4, success-message, newsletter-subscriber, error-message

How to move Success, Error messages position on top for home page only (others are already on top)?

I want to display  Newsletter Subscription Message on top instead of bottom for home page only.rest of the places it's showing on top.

this is manage from the following controller:-

Magento\Newsletter\Controller\Subscriber\NewAction.php::execute()

I also tried to do the same from JS but it's not working.when i directly hitting my JS code on browser console then it's moving the message on top but when i tried Magento2 way then it's not working.

Here is the JS code:-

**subscribe-newsletter.js:-**

```
requirejs(['jquery'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){
            console.log("Hey123") ;
    $(".message-error").insertBefore(".feature_product");
    });
});
```

**Path:-** app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto_child/web/js/subscribe-newsletter.js

**layout cms_index_index.xml:-**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
       <script src="js/subscribe-newsletter.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>              
    </body>
</page>
```

**Screenshot:-** https://nimb.ws/jHrfZh

Please help me to resolve!!!

Answer (score 0):

Installed 3rd Party **Free** Ext. **PHPCuong_Newsletter** and it works for me.

Actually this ext. uses AJAX,you can download from Git.

Thanks!!!